# Bad Argument when importing a webpage in Microsoft's QNA Maker

Tags: azure-qna-maker

In QNA Maker:

1. I try to import a webpage: https://www.xtopia.io/_testing/huisheng/faqtest.html
2. Received error: 
   Bad Argument
   Failed to extract QnAs from the source https://www.xtopia.io/_testing/huisheng/faqtest.html - Unsupported / Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source
3. How do I know what is the problem?

Thanks

Searched for [QNA Maker] Bad Argument but no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error means that QnAMaker does not support the file format/URL uploaded. QnAMaker supports a certain set of files and URL data types. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/data-sources-supported), QnAMaker allows the following file formats for creating a knowledge base: PDF,word, xls, tsv and txt. What you can do is convert the .html to pdf/tsv/txt file and then upload it to populate your KB on the QnAMAker portal.

The linked documentation will give you a better idea of what formats the QnAMaker accepts.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: We managed to upload some URLs before in accordion format.
But this page cannot. So, wondering if there is some html syntax in the page that is causing the error. Is there a way to check the log or debug the URL for more information?

Comment: It's not the HTML syntax, but got to do more with the way the questions are encoded on the page which is preventing the QnAMaker's services from reading the text of the question/answer pairs.

Comment: I found out in another page, if there are only 2 qna, it will show Bad Argument.
But if we add the 3rd qna and more, then it can proceed. Hopefully QNA Maker can give a more meaningful error message in future.